# BindingSource with DataGridView Combo Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I know you can use the `BindingSource` object with a DataGridView.

Is it possible to have a combo box in one of the columns and still take advantage of the `BindingSource`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is - take a look at [ComboBox with DataGridView in C#](http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/combobox-with-datagridview-in-c/):

> Using ComboBox with DataGridView is not that complex anymore but it’s almost mandatory while doing some data driven software development.
>
> [image]
>
> I have created a DataGridView like this one. Now, I want to show “Month” and “Item” instead of “MonthID” and “ItemID” in DataGridView.

Essentially what the article describes is binding the comboboxes with a separate binding source - in this case, a validation table, where `MonthID` and `MonthName` are stored, and the month name is displayed based on the id from the original data.

Here he sets up the Month data source, selecting from a month table, and then creates a `BindingSource` from the returned data.

```
//Month Data Source
string selectQueryStringMonth = "SELECT MonthID,MonthText FROM Table_Month";
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapterMonth = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryStringMonth, sqlConnection);
SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilderMonth = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapterMonth);
DataTable dataTableMonth= new DataTable();
sqlDataAdapterMonth.Fill(dataTableMonth);
BindingSource bindingSourceMonth = new BindingSource();
bindingSourceMonth.DataSource = dataTableMonth;
```

Then he adds the month ComboBoxColumn to the DataGridView, using the `DataSource` as the `BindingSource` created above:

```
//Adding  Month Combo
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColumnMonth = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
ColumnMonth.DataPropertyName = "MonthID";
ColumnMonth.HeaderText = "Month";
ColumnMonth.Width = 120;
ColumnMonth.DataSource = bindingSourceMonth;
ColumnMonth.ValueMember = "MonthID";
ColumnMonth.DisplayMember = "MonthText";
dataGridViewComboTrial.Columns.Add(ColumnMonth);
```

And then finally, he binds the `DataGridView` to the original data.