# Sql to datagridview combobox

Tags: c#

Hi i'm using this code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,country from customers", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
```

But what if my first cell is a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {

    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell ContactCombo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1]);
            ContactCombo.Value = item[0].ToString();

    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
    }
```

this code will gives you datagridview dropdown you can do anything(add items, select items, remove items) with this

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell ContactCombo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(Add data gridview cell index here);
```

Comment: I get error Cannot use local variable 'row' before it is declared

Comment: Error Error 1 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What you mean?add you data grid viwe cell index here.You mean this?dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0]

Comment: [Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829621/bindingsource-with-datagridview-combo-box)

Comment: I dont want take item on dropdown, i want to take the value from sql as combobox's name